# MySQL INDEX join same table on different columns

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

**A simplified version of my dataset:**

I have a table with 2 columns `col1` and `col2`

I want to optimize this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b
ON a.col1 = b.col2
```

What is the best index to create on this table?

- Two indices: index on `col1` and another on `col2`
- One double index: index on both `col1,col2`

**Let's complicate it a bit: (my real-life data structure)**

Say I also have a column `extract_date` in my table:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b
ON a.col1 = b.col2 AND a.extract_date=b.extract_date
```

What is the best index to create on this table?

- Two double indices: index1 on `col1,extract_date` and another on `col2,extract_date`
- One triple index: index on `col1,col2,extract_date`

Comment: basic rule of thumb: any field used in a "decision context": a where clause, an order by, a group by, etc... should be indexed. how you could go about building those indexes up to you.

Comment: I don't agree... i've seen there are guidelines depending on the granularity of the dataset, and if MySQL decides to use it or not

Comment: well, yeah, if it's a 10 record table, index would be overkill.

Comment: i'm talking about millions of rows. And by granularity, I mean distinct values of each column: col1 has 10 distinct values, col2 has 1000 distinct values

Comment: then indexes will still help in most cases. there's no hard/fast rule that says "indexes of type X and quantity Y will cause Z% performance increase". you'll have to test it both ways. if your particular data set proves out that indexes don't help, then don't waste the overhead of creating/maintaining that index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `a.col1 = b.col2`, `col1` and `col2` are in *separate* tables.  (Never mind that it is a self-join; that is irrelevant for creating an index.)

For the more complex query, again, consider each table separately.  These are optimal:

```
INDEX(col1, extract_date) -- in either order, and
INDEX(col2, extract_date) -- also in either order.
```

I agree with Marcus and Consider; see my [Index Cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).  And you get only one crack at 'ranges'.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best index to create on this table?
>
> - Two indices: index on `col1` and another on `col2`
> - One double index: index on both `col1,col2`

A two-column index does not optimize your query the way two one-column indexes would do.

[From MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), bold emphasis mine:

> MySQL can use multiple-column indexes **for queries that test all the columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column**, the first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. If you specify the columns in the right order in the index definition, a single composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same table.

From what you can read above multiple-column indexes can be used by MySQL engine when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost) columns.

So your particular query wouldn't benefit from index on `col1,col2` as much as two separate indices, since this index would not be used for lookup considering `= b.col2` part of your `JOIN` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b
ON a.col1 = b.col2
```

As for your "real" data structure, the above still applies.

**Note**: A rule of thumb is to index for equality first, and then for ranges. **Markus Winand** backs me up in [his book](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates) that treats about indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two indexes. All the columns in a composite index can only be used when the `WHERE` clause is of the form

```
WHERE a.col1 = something AND a.col2 = somethingelse AND a.col3 = thirdthing ...
```

A condition like `a.col1 = b.col2` doesn't match that pattern, because `a` and `b` are different instances of the table.

Comment: I think the real point is that col1 and col2 are in 'different' tables.

Comment: @RickJames Right, I wasn't sure how to express it when I wrote my answer. I've clarified by adding aliases to the example.